# Create objects on demand

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance

I am working in a kind of notification system for a web and I would like to create an object for every notification in order to get track of the unread or read notifications.
For example I got something like this one:

```
var Notifications = function(){
    this.read = false;
};

Notifications.prototype.open = function(){
    alert('opening');
}

Notifications.prototype.close = function(){
    alert('close');
}

Notifications.prototype.fetchInfo = function(){
    alert('fetching info from browser');
}

Notifications.prototype.remove = function(){
    alert('removing notification');
}

var someNotification = new Notification();
```

what i would actually want to do is every time a resiebe an event from a socket create a new notification like:

```
socket.on('notification', function(){
    var notification1 = new Notification();
});
```

and now if a get a new notification create

```
 var notification2 = new Notifications();
```

I would like to know hoy can i dinamically create this notification objects or if you guys know a better way to handle this problem, i appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try an array:

```
var notifications = [];
socket.on('notification', function(){
    var notification = new Notification();
    notifications.push(notification);
});
```

Notification should be new each time event is triggered:

```
    var notification = new Notification();
```

Comment: but then how can i point to one of the notifications?

`notifications[0].open();` ?

Comment: Going to give it a try, tell you later how is going